# Dynamic CMS pages and static pages CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter-2

I'm using Codeigniter 2, and i have some dynamic pages (CMS) which are created from the back office and have the page name as ID . And some pages are static , there is a example :

Dynamic pages :

```
www.domain.com/privacy
www.domain.com/about
```

and static page  :

```
www.domain.com/invitation
```

So the question is how can route this pages : i tried to use :

```
 $route['([a-z0-9\-]+)'] = 'home/cms/$1';
```

But it gives me 404 for static pages ( `www.domain.com/invitation` )

Any help and thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can either explicitly remove the static files from the redirection in your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(invitation\.php|index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

or, you can use the [`_remap` function](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html#remapping). Inside the `_remap` function, you would check for existence of a physical file for your "method" - if there, load it - if not, route to the controller method:

```
public function _remap($method, $params = array())
{
    $filepath = BASEPATH.$method.".php";
    if (file_exists($filepath))
    {
        include($filepath);
        return;
    }
    else if (method_exists($this, $method))
    {
        return call_user_func_array(array($this, $method), $params);
    }
    else
    {
        show_404();
    }
}
```